# ReSharper giving C# 3.0 Code Inspection Warnings to .NET 2.0 Projects

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-2.0, resharper

When I am working in .NET 2.0 projects with the newest version of ReSharper (4.1) I am getting warnings about using the var keyword and lambadas etc.. Any idea how I can disable this only for .NET 2.0 projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, you can use C# 3.0 compiler features when targeting .NET 2.0, except extension methods and default LINQ implementations, which are located in newer assemblies. But if you need to co-operate with VS2005 users, you can open Properties view for a given project (not Project Properties, but Edit \ Properties Window, or F4) and select desired language level.

Comment: This works for class libraries and I am assuming applications, but I don't see this same option for my ASP.NET website.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use var in 2.0 projects.  It's syntactical sugar and the compiler works with it. Check out this for more info.

http://weblogs.asp.net/shahar/archive/2008/01/23/use-c-3-features-from-c-2-and-net-2-0-code.aspx

Comment: What if the project has to be opened in both Visual Studio 2005 & 2008.  (Not same Greg as asker)

Comment: Good question.  Don't have 2005 on this box.  Will try it out at the office on Monday.

Comment: VS 2005 doesn't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Moth has a great [blog post](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2007/05/using-c-30-from-net-20.html) on how to using C# 3.0 features (including extension methods) in .Net 2.0.

After rereading the question, this really doesn't help. You can turn off specific inspections via the R# Options window. I don't know of a way to switch back and forth between 2.0 and 3.5 project settings without manually changing them :S.